# Tomar un valor de fila de Pentaho Rport

Tags: pentaho

Buenas estoy usando pentaho report y me gustaría hacer una gráfica con los resultados de una sumatoria que ya hay hecha en el informe. Me gustaría saber como puedo tomar esos valores. Imagino que habrá que hacer un campo numérico para almacenar el dato.

```
Nombre    Nivel     Valor 1     Valor 2
----------------------------------------
NOmbre1   2          545          214
NOmbre2   3          23423         23423
NOmbre3   2          234            3434
NOmbre4   6          234            234
```

etc........

La pregunta es: Como podría yo tomar  valor1 y valor 2 dependiendo del nivel
ALgo como... `=IF([Nivel]=2)`   A mi campo Numero1 le asigno Valor1 y a mi campo Numero2 le asigno Valor2

**Tomar dos valores de la misma fila dependiendo del valor Nivel**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar como lo intentas, determinas si "Nivel" tiene el valor de 2 y obtienes el valor de las columnas en este caso `[Valor 1]` y `[Valor 2]`, en este caso lo ideal sería usar la función SUM() para obtener la suma de los valores en ambas columnas, de otra forma usas `NA()` para obtener un null.

Ejemplo:

```
= IF ([Nivel] = 2; SUM([Valor 1][Valor 2]); NA())
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, suppongo que esa formula se la tendré que aplicar a un campo numérico no? Mi intención es hacer una grafica despúes con esos dos campos. Un campo será la suma de valor 1 si nivel 2 y otra la suma de valor 2 si nivel 2. Con ese resultado hago la grafica.

Comment: @LorenzoMartín Si con ese resultado realiza la gráfica, solo un comentario, si tus columnas  "Nivel" son de tipo "Number" podrías optar por usar 0 en lugar de NA() de esta forma: = IF ([Nivel] = 2; SUM([Valor 1][Valor 2]); 0))

Comment: Hay una cosa que no entiendo, disculpa mi torpeza. Yo tengo que crear dos campos de tipo numérico. Uno para la suma de valor1 y otro para la suma de valor 2. Esa fórmula tendré que usarla dos veces no?  Lo que no entiendo es por que lo de SUM([valor 1][valor 2]). Yo en mi caso tendria que poner solo SUM([valor 1])     y SUM([valor2]